# Placing Multilple Google Charts on webpage from MYSQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I have been able to show a google chart from mysql data, but when I add the second chart I am only able to see the data from the 2nd array(for 2nd chart) I used json_encode on in my php script.  If I change the order of the array encoding so that the 2nd chart's array is now encoded first I no longer see it, but now the first chart is visible.  **Can anyone see the issue?**  Maybe I should use column charts   instead of material charts??
here is my javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

    function drawCharts() {
    drawChartA();
    drawChartB(); 

    }

        function drawChartB(){
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
          var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Calls for <?php echo $cLabel;?>',
                    subtitle: 'Something to put Here',



                },
                annotations:{
                    textStyle:{
                        fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        bold: true,
                        italic: false
                    }
                },
                width: 1200,
                height: 600,


            };

          var chart = new 
          google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        }

          function drawChartA(){
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable_ct?>);
          var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Calls for <?php echo $cLabel;?>',
                    subtitle: 'Something to put Here',

                },
                annotations:{
                    textStyle:{
                        fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        bold: true,
                        italic: false
                    }
                },
                width: 1200,
                height: 600,
                isStacked: 'true',

            };

 var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div_ct'));

          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        }

</script>
```

my json_encoded files are:

```
    {"cols":[{"label":"Time Interval","type":"string"},{"label":"Calls - All Offices","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"05:00"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"06:00"},{"v":3}]},{"c":[{"v":"07:00"},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"v":"07:30"},{"v":22}]},{"c":[{"v":"08:00"},{"v":82}]},{"c":[{"v":"08:30"},{"v":68}]},{"c":[{"v":"09:00"},{"v":97}]},{"c":[{"v":"09:30"},{"v":48}]},{"c":[{"v":"10:00"},{"v":56}]},{"c":[{"v":"10:30"},{"v":70}]},{"c":[{"v":"11:00"},{"v":75}]},{"c":[{"v":"11:30"},{"v":53}]},{"c":[{"v":"12:00"},{"v":56}]},{"c":[{"v":"12:30"},{"v":48}]},{"c":[{"v":"13:00"},{"v":22}]},{"c":[{"v":"13:30"},{"v":42}]},{"c":[{"v":"14:00"},{"v":40}]},{"c":[{"v":"14:30"},{"v":60}]},{"c":[{"v":"15:00"},{"v":69}]},{"c":[{"v":"15:30"},{"v":65}]},{"c":[{"v":"16:00"},{"v":73}]},{"c":[{"v":"16:30"},{"v":37}]},{"c":[{"v":"17:00"},{"v":20}]},{"c":[{"v":"17:30"},{"v":10}]},{"c":[{"v":"18:00"},{"v":10}]},{"c":[{"v":"18:30"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"19:00"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"19:30"},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"20:00"},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"20:30"},{"v":1}]}]}
```

and the other is here: (they both work so reviewing this may not be necessary)

```
    {"cols":[{"label":"Time Interval","type":"string"},{"label":"NP Calls","type":"number"},{"label":"DR Calls","type":"number"},{"label":"RE Today Calls","type":"number"},{"label":"RE Future","type":"number"},{"label":"ACCT","type":"number"},{"label":"EMER","type":"number"},{"label":"Other Calls","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"05:00"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"06:00"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"07:00"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"07:30"},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":3},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"08:00"},{"v":9},{"v":3},{"v":11},{"v":5},{"v":0},{"v":4},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"08:30"},{"v":1},{"v":2},{"v":13},{"v":7},{"v":2},{"v":4},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"09:00"},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":15},{"v":11},{"v":6},{"v":3},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"09:30"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":4},{"v":6},{"v":5},{"v":0},{"v":16}]},{"c":[{"v":"10:00"},{"v":1},{"v":3},{"v":2},{"v":10},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":17}]},{"c":[{"v":"10:30"},{"v":5},{"v":1},{"v":1},{"v":10},{"v":2},{"v":3},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"11:00"},{"v":5},{"v":3},{"v":7},{"v":11},{"v":10},{"v":1},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"11:30"},{"v":4},{"v":1},{"v":2},{"v":6},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":18}]},{"c":[{"v":"12:00"},{"v":3},{"v":0},{"v":5},{"v":11},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":21}]},{"c":[{"v":"12:30"},{"v":5},{"v":1},{"v":4},{"v":4},{"v":4},{"v":1},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"13:00"},{"v":2},{"v":1},{"v":3},{"v":2},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":6}]},{"c":[{"v":"13:30"},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":15}]},{"c":[{"v":"14:00"},{"v":5},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":5},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":4}]},{"c":[{"v":"14:30"},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":5},{"v":6},{"v":6},{"v":0},{"v":19}]},{"c":[{"v":"15:00"},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":4},{"v":8},{"v":4},{"v":1},{"v":22}]},{"c":[{"v":"15:30"},{"v":8},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":10},{"v":4},{"v":0},{"v":22}]},{"c":[{"v":"16:00"},{"v":6},{"v":5},{"v":1},{"v":12},{"v":3},{"v":2},{"v":20}]},{"c":[{"v":"16:30"},{"v":3},{"v":4},{"v":3},{"v":7},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":7}]},{"c":[{"v":"17:00"},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":4},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"17:30"},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":1}]},{"c":[{"v":"18:00"},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"18:30"},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]}]}Can
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely [the same issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2066) that was reported in [google-visualization-issues](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues) repository.

There are at least two solution available at the moment:

**Option 1. Render charts synchronously**

The general idea is to render chart synchronously. Since draw function is asyncronous, we utilize `ready` event handler for that purpose.

Place `ready` event handler in every function before `draw` function invocation:

```
if (typeof ready != "undefined") google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', ready);
```

and change `drawChartN()` function signature to `drawChartN(ready)`

Then replace:

```
function drawCharts() {
    drawChartA();
    drawChartB();
}
```

with:

```
function drawCharts() {
    drawChartA(function(){
        drawChartB();
    });
}
```

[**PhpFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5zfw-nsan)

**Option 2. Using the frozen version loader.**

Since

> The rollout of the v43 candidate release that would fix this problem

switch to using the frozen version loader.

Steps:

1)Add a reference to loader: `<script
   src="//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

2)Then load a 43 version of library: `google.charts.load("43",{packages:["corechart","bar"]});`

3)Replace:

```
function drawCharts() {
    drawChartA();
    drawChartB();
}
```

with

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartA);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartB);
```